# Generating image from sql data

Tags: sql, database, image

I am looking to generate an image from database information.
This is a feature used in many community websites to allow users to generate an image with their profile information to share in forum signatures and so on.

I have seen this executed by either generating an image link, or an embed code.

I understand this will probably not be a short answer, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction so I can research it.

Thankyou.